# Grab multi select list values and rewrite as anchors with JavaScript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi everyone and thanks for looking. I have a multiselect list on a page that's been pre-populated from a database.

I now need to grab all data from the list and turn it into separate links The drop-down could in theory be of any length and the list value is used as the record ID, so...

```
<select id="Inf1">
        <option value="147">Art Tatum</option>
        <option value="151">Charles Mingus</option>
        <option value="172">John Coltrane</option>
    </select>
```

should be re-written as:

```
<div id="Artists">
<a href="/tabid/89/xmmid/393/xmid/147/xmview/3/default.aspx">Art Tatum</a>
<a href="/tabid/89/xmmid/393/xmid/151/xmview/3/default.aspx">Charles Mingus</a>
<a href="/tabid/89/xmmid/393/xmid/172/xmview/3/default.aspx">John Coltrane</a>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#Inf1 option").each(function () {
        var id, text;
        id = $(this).val();
        text = $(this).text();
        $("#Artists").append("<a href='/tabid/89/xmmid/393/xmid/"+id+"/xmview/3/default.aspx'>"+text+"</a>");
    });
```

Something like this should work, here's a jsfiddle as well, even though I strongly suggest you create the links on the server instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/nQsTF/

Comment: finally `$('#Einf1').remove()` will complete his requirement. :)

Comment: @Everyone You all quite rightly say this should be formed on the server. I'm working with a Forms manager on DotNetNuke which writes out all each record as one big lump of XML. I've tried targeting this for a while using SQL and failed, hence doing it this way. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jQuery solution

```
$(function() {
    var options = $('#Inf1')[0].options;

    var div =  $('<div id="Artists">');
    for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
        div.append($('<a href="/tabid/89/xmmid/393/xmid/'+options[i].value+'/xmview/3/default.aspx">' + options[i].text+ '</a>'));
    }

    div.appendTo('body');

});
```

and here a jsFiddle for demonstration http://jsfiddle.net/7GhXE/1/

Comment: Thanks for this. Your solution works well however I've marked Stefan's answer as correct as it's slightly leaner code. Sorry...!

Answer (score 0):

Why go to the effort of creating a dropdown list on the server and then using up the clients resources to convert it to hyperlinks?

Just generate the hyperlinks on the server in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

this code will return the div you want in the variable named "result", whatever the length of your list. It's cross-browser and you don't need any library.

```
var result = (function (){
    var rv = document.createElement("div");
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("Inf1");
    var options = dropdown.options;
    for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
        var option = options[i];
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = "/tabid/89/xmmid/393/xmid/" + option.value + "/xmview/3/default.aspx";
        a.innerHTML = option.text;
        rv.appendChild(a);
        }
    rv.id = "Artists";
    return rv;
    })();
```

// Now you just have to embed the output div where you want in your page, using document.body.appendChild(result), for instance.